# mahapps SplitButton expand on click

Tags: mahapps.metro

I defined a SplitButton in WPF(C#) with a binded item source.

The item list will be expanded only when the user clicks on the arrow at the right of the SplitButton.

How to expand the list when the user clicks on the SplitButton area?

I tried to handle the click event and set the property IsExpanded=true, but it automatically disappears after one second.

```
<Controls:SplitButton Name="SplitButton_Test"
              Width="100"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Dictionary_Test}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Value"
              SelectedValuePath="Key"
              Click="Test_Click">
    <Controls:SplitButton.Icon>
        <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Margin="6" Kind="Alert" />
    </Controls:SplitButton.Icon>
</Controls:SplitButton>

private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (SplitButton_Test.IsExpanded == false)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        SplitButton_Test.IsExpanded = true; //Doesn't work, closes automatically after 1 second
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code in MahApps is closing it:

```c#
 //Make popup close even if no selectionchanged event fired (case when user select the save item as before)
    void ListBoxPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = ContainerFromElement(_listBox, e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as ListBoxItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            IsExpanded = false;
        }
    }
```

currently at https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro.Shared/Controls/SplitButton.cs#L339

You need to remove that event handler. How? That's whole other question.

Comment: Thanks! How can I remove it cleanly? :)

Comment: I don't know. I searched here and there are questions and answers but I didn't try any. One way is to build MahApps from the source and remove that code. It may actually be the easiest way.